# Limit on max live access_tokens for Firebase Cloud Messenging

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, android-push-notification

I want to send push notifications to millions of devices in parallel from bunch of servers. Each server will run workers that will call Google auth end point to fetch auth_token for a FCM project and use that token for sending push notification to devices.

Is there any limit of max live auth_tokens for a FCM project ?

Did not find any documentation around limit.